# how to update OpenLDAP directory attribute?

Tags: openldap

Is there any way to programmatically update the OpenLDAP directory attribute through Java code?

Comment: Err, JNDI? It's built right in.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using Novell's [LDAP Classes for Java](http://developer.novell.com/wiki/index.php/LDAP_Classes_for_Java), which do the job just fine for us.

Answer (score 1):

Peter is right, these classes are the only ones available as long you do not want to fiddle around with JNDI.

One thing though you if you update an attribute you will need to remove the value of the attribute before you add a new value (especially with multivalued attributes).

Comment: Or use the replace modification type.